# I accidentally tweeted someone, if I delete it straight after will they still know?

Tags: twitter

I accidentally tweeted someone, but I deleted it straight after. Will they still get a notification or an e-mail?

Comment: I would expect so. Was it an @reply or a direct message?

Comment: It was an @reply but I didn't write anything. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they should still get the notifications via email, though they will not be able to find the tweet itself by following the link in the email. Of course you may be lucky and Twitter may wait a minute or so before sending out an email notification.